# Slide View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I have a project in UIKit, with a Calendar. I implemented a slide animation every time the month is changed.

[image]

This was the code:

```
/// Desliza una vista hacia derecha o izquierda
///
/// - Parameter direccion: Dirección de desplazamiento
func deslizarHacia(_ direccion:DireccionDeslizamiento, tipoTransicion: CATransitionType = .push) {
    
    let slideInFromLeftTransition = CATransition()

    // Customize the animation's properties
    slideInFromLeftTransition.type = CATransitionType.push
    slideInFromLeftTransition.subtype = convertToOptionalCATransitionSubtype((direccion == .derecha) ? CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft.rawValue : CATransitionSubtype.fromRight.rawValue)
    slideInFromLeftTransition.duration = 0.3
    slideInFromLeftTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    slideInFromLeftTransition.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.removed
    
    // Add the animation to the View's layer
    self.layer.add(slideInFromLeftTransition, forKey: (direccion == .derecha) ? "slideInFromLeftTransition" : "slideInFromRightTransition")
    
}
```

Now I'm working on the same app on SwiftUI, but I'm not able to have the same animation.

This is the actual code in SwiftUI (obviously, the app code is very much complex, but it works like the app).

```
struct PruebasDrag: View {
    
    @State var num = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Button("<") {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        num -= 1
                    }
                }
                Button(">") {
                    withAnimation {
                        num += 1
                    }
                }
            }
            Text(String(num))
                .transition(.slide)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.mint)
                .contentTransition(.interpolate)
                
            Spacer()
        }
        
        .font(.title)
    }
}
```

When the month changes, the data inside the calendar (VStack and HStack) is changed, but it's the same View. I try to apply .transition(.slide) to the view, with no effect.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include your current SwiftUI code as well, which isn't working.

Comment: Done, not the code from the app, but useful for the example.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make a custom animation. you would need to create a new variable to store the animations value and then a function to updated it

for example you could go

```
@State var AnimationAmount = 0
```

And then

```
func CustomSlidingAnimation(XOffset: Int, FinalX: Int, Speed: Double) {
    // Controls the speed of the loop=
    // Larger Double Number = Longer Animation
  
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Speed {
        var newPosition = XOffset + 1
        AnimationAmount = newPosition
        if (NewPosition == Final Position) {
           //Ends The Loop
           // Put Boolean here to stop displaying a view

        } else {
            CustomSlidingAnimation(XOffset: newPosition, FinalX: FinalX, Speed: Speed)
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use your animation amount value in the offset variable on a view. and have the animation play by calling the function with the Offset value set too 0 so it starts the animation from a zero offset, you can also set the view that's being moved in the animation to have a boolean where it stops showing the view when the animation is over and then set it to false when ever it has reach the finalX :P I hope this is able to work for you! :P